# How can I pass an Object Attribute from my parent to a children in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to pass for example the ID of a VPC, which lives in the parent, to a Module in Terraform. I already figured out that I can do so by using the `Outputs.tf`, initialize a variable in the `variables.tf` in the children and value it in the "module" in the parents `main.tf`. If you would do the same the other way, you'd just have to say for example

```
module "example"{
vpc_id = module.network.vpc.id
}
```

But as I need it the other way around, I can't say module.network. How would I have to do this, when I#m referring to an Object of the Parent?

Comment: You wrote that "Thanks, everything worked fine" so why not accept the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your VPC is named "main" like in [the official examples](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/vpc).

To reference the ID anywhere in the parent Terraform template, you would use `aws_vpc.main.id`.

So to pass that to a module, it would look like this;

```
module "example"{
   vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id
}
```

Comment: That answer came quick^^ Thanks, everything worked fine.